# How to generate output depending on whether or not a userkey has been defined

Tags: latex, glossaries

I would like to modify the glossaryentryfield so that it creates output depending on whether or not user1 (key provided by the package has been defined/set or not. I tried the following:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{\bfseries{\glstarget{##1}{##2}} & ##3 \\
\ifempty{\glsentryuseri{##1}}
    it & is very empty \\
\else
    & \glsentryuseri{##1} \\%
\fi}
```

which however results in several errormessages like this:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \ifempty 
>                             l.49   \setentrycounter{page}\glsnumberformat{a}}}
>                                                     % The control sequence at the end of
>   the top line of your error message was
>   never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
>   it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the
>   correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll
>   forget about whatever was undefined.

(One for every Glossary entry it seems) obviously followed by an unmatched \else and unmatched \fi

As far as i can see, i have to do something with the expansion order, however i am a complete novice to latex.
I can not simply set all user1-keys, since i want to only display that extra row if user1 is defined, the other row is just for debugging purposes.

I also tried to add \expandafter directly before the \if ( \expandafter\ifempty{\glsentryuseri{##1}} ) (resulting in the following output:)

> user1value it & is very empty \\ & user1value

since nobody could awnser this i crossposted it at [the latex community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9480) and added a minimal example there. As soon as it gets awnsered on one site i will crosspost the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicola Talbot awnsered my question on the [latex community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9480#p36500), she wrote:

> \ifempty isn't defined in standard
>   LaTeX, which is what's causing the
>   error message. You can use the ifmtarg
>   package, which provides the internal
>   command \@ifmtarg. For example:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage{ifmtarg}
> \usepackage[style=long]{glossaries}
>
> \makeglossaries
>
> \makeatletter
> \newcommand*{\ifuseriempty}[3]{%
>   \protected@edef\tmp{\glsentryuseri{#1}}%
>   \expandafter\@ifmtarg\expandafter{\tmp}{#2}{#3}%
> }
> \makeatother
>
> \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{\bfseries{\glstarget{#1}{#2}}
> & #3 \\
> \ifuseriempty{#1}%
>   {it &is very empty}%
>   { &\glsentryuseri{#1}}%
> \\%
> }
>
> \newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,%
>   description={sample without user 1 key}}
>
> \newglossaryentry{sample2}{name=sample2,%
>   description={sample with user 1 key},
>   user1={User1 Value}}
>
> \begin{document}
> \gls{sample}, \gls{sample2}.
>
> \printglossaries
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> Regards Nicola Talbot

For my purposes the glossaryentryfield has to look like this:

\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{\bfseries{\glstarget{#1}{#2}}
   & #3 \
   \ifuseriempty{#1}%
      {}%
      { &\glsentryuseri{#1}\}%
    }

Remember to use ## instead of # infront of the parameter numbers if you want to use this in a \newglossarystyle enviornment